# Call a jQuery function when a button is being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set jQuery a function on its own, and call the function when a click event triggers. Here's the code I've managed to come up with:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control email_input" name='email' id="reserve_email_1" placeholder="Email">
                <span class='input-group-btn'>

                  <button type="submit" id="subscribe_1" class="btn btn-success subscribe_button">Send now</button>

</span>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.subscribe_button').click(function(){
$.fn.Subscribe();
 });

 $.fn.Subscribe = function(){ 
  var email = $(this).parent().siblings('.email_input').val();
  alert(email);
} 

});
```

But no matter what values I have in the email input, it would not pop up in the alert. I tested and don't think it's the wrong traversing order, but rather the first function failed to call the 2nd function. Any advice on why it would happen?

Best,

Answer (score 4):

`Subscribe` is a plugin method, so you need to invoke it like a jQuery plugin like(so that the method will get proper context value for `this`)

```
$('.subscribe_button').click(function () {
    $(this).Subscribe();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MW4Uz/)